# Tesseract use multiple core for one image

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I want to use tesseract with multiple core for one image because I run tesseract on Raspberry Pi 3B and tesseract is too slow(1 minute for 1 image). I tried to crop image and process them with multiple cores, but this was slower. I made lots of research, but I couldn't find anything. Thank you.

Comment: Consider using `top -H -p <pid>` where <pid> is pid of your tesseract process to see how much CPU does it use.

Answer (score 0):

Even using multiple cores, you have to consider that the memory in the Raspberry may no be enough to feed each core with data faster than one would do for the whole image.
1 minute for an intensive operation as is OCR with a Raspberry Pi is not so bad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that Rapsberry Pi is not good for OCR, but I have to do it, so I'm searching for solution.

Comment: If it's for an embedded system but it's connected through the network, you could use the Raspberry just to send the image to a different, more powerful, system.